# cron job running an hour early due to daylight savings

Tags: cron, date

On a `CentOS 7.5.1804` host I am experiencing a cronjob that is running an hour early due to rolling the clocks back an hour and the [UTC offset changing from UTC-4 to UTC-5](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/aboututc.shtml).

This runs from `/etc/cron.d/*`

```
# Runs at 1410 UTC on M-F
10 14 * * 1-5 accountchecker bash /opt/accountchecker/accountchecker.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I want this to run at 1010 M-F Eastern Time, but because the host is UTC it's respecting the hour change and running now at 910 Eastern Time.

How can I have cron accommodate this change and consistently run at 1010?

Comment: yeah, that's the trouble with using UTC, unfortunately.  Can't you change system's time to your timezone?

Comment: Kahn, which crontab file is this in - root's own (`crontab -l`) or one of the system ones under `/etc/cron*`? If the latter, which one?

Comment: Sorry @roaima, let me amend my question to reflect that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the time zone of a cronjob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195818/change-the-time-zone-of-a-cronjob)  See also [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+cron+timezone&t=ffab&atb=v211-1&ia=web).

Answer (score 0):

I've only had to go the other way -- to make sure something ran at a consistent UTC time.

I set the crontab to run at the potentially earlier time, test if the time is too early, and if so, sleep for an hour.

If you have processes that monitor for 'stuck' cronjobs (running too long), you could make a wrapper that tested for the correct time and then either did nothing or let the program run ... and then put that in cron it at both times that might be correct.

As I'm comparing to UTC, I can just look at `date -u` ... you'd want to compare against `TZ=America/Los_Angeles date` (or whatever your appropriate timezone file is)